# How to compute perform a javascript/jquery computation using loops from PHP data?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I created a loop in my **PHP** file that generates 10 rows. Each row has four boxes and below is the grand total.

The scenario is, when the user enters a qty and a price, the total will automatically change using **jQuery** and the grand total also. And the same with `row2`. My problem is, I can't access the `id` from my **PHP** `input` fields.

Here's what I did:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++){
    echo "<!-- ITEM {$i} -->";
    echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td><input type='text' name='qty{$i}' class='k-textbox' id='qty{$i}'></td>";
       echo "<td><input type='text' name='item{$i}' class='k-textbox' id='item{$i}'></td>";
       echo "<td><input type='text' name='price{$i}' class='k-textbox' id='price{$i}'></td>";
       echo "<td><input type='text' name='total{$i}' class='k-textbox' id='total{$i}'></td>";
    echo "<tr>";
}
<tr>
   <td>GRAND TOTAL</td>
   <td><input type='text' name='gtotal' value='0.00' id='gtotal' class='k-textbox' />
</tr>
```

Here's my **jQuery** code:

```
var x = 0;

for(x = 1; x < 11; x++){
  $('#qty'+x, '#price'+x).on('input',function() {
     var qty = parseInt($('#qty'+x).val());
     var price = parseFloat($('#price'+x).val());
      $('#total'+x).val((qty * price ? qty * price : 0).toFixed(2));
  });
}
```

That's all. I hope you can help me.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: I'm so confused... Why do you need PHP to access the ID from the input fields anyways? Isn't he PHP the one defining the IDs?

Comment: The question is very simply there is a much better way to do this

Comment: I need the ID of the inputs for my jquery. Are there any other way to perform this logic?

Comment: there you go check my answer, its less messy and no javascript loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't `input` event.

It's easy to get `id` attribute, what you really need to do is to add `$(documnet).ready(..)` and replace `input` event to `change` event.

So, update js code:

**UPDATE: I mistook to use** `# selector` **, and have updated it to** `[id^=...]`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // well,$('selector1,selector2')  not  $('selector1','selector2')
    $('[id^=qty] , [id^=price]').on('change',function() {
        var index=this.id.match(/\d+/)[0];
        var qty = parseInt($('#qty'+index).val());
        var price = parseFloat($('#price'+index).val());
        $('#total'+index).val((qty * price ? qty * price : 0).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Comment: @user2585508 That's because I made a mistake, try to use `parseInt` but got `NaN`.I have replaced `parseInt` to regular expression.I think it works.Have a try.

Comment: still not working. do you have an email so that i can send you my whole code? and please tell me what's y error.

Comment: @user2585508 zhang6464@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding the question correctly but why not have PHP calculate the grand total and then place the value in the grand total?

Comment: Because i want to do it in a my client side.

Answer (score 0):

first you generate your html as follows, lets use your class to attach the trigger, and define a custom type called `data-type` to test against and also add `data-row` to keep track of the row your in.

```
for($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++){
    echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td><input type='text' data-row='{$i}' data-type='qty' name='qty{$i}' class='k-textbox' id='qty{$i}'></td>";
       echo "<td><input type='text' data-row='{$i}' data-type='item' name='item{$i}' class='k-textbox' id='item{$i}'></td>";
       echo "<td><input type='text' data-row='{$i}' data-type='price' name='price{$i}' class='k-textbox' id='price{$i}'></td>";
       echo "<td><input type='text' data-row='{$i}' data-type='total' name='total{$i}' class='k-textbox' id='total{$i}'></td>";
    echo "<tr>";
}
```

then lets work on the jquery without any need for redundant loops

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
          $(".k-textbox").input(function (evt) {
               var that = $(this);
               if (that.attr('data-type') != 'price' && that.attr('data-type') != 'qty) return;
               var row = that.attr('data-row');
               var qty = parseInt($('#qty'+row).val());
               var price = parseFloat($('#price'+row).val());
               $('#total'+row).val((qty * price ? qty * price : 0).toFixed(2));
          });
    });
</script>
```